# Eclipse BIRT scripted report: 'Invalid javascript expression: dataSetRow' exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, birt

I am using Eclipse's BIRT to render a report through Java using `org.eclipse.birt.runtime` version `4.4.0`.

When attempting to render the report, BIRT is returning:

`org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Invalid Javascript expression: dataSetRow["name"].`
 (and similar errors for each `dataSetRow` and `row`) in `.getErrors()` of the `IRunAndRenderTask`;

The template works fine using the BIRT designer and rendering it through that application, but it breaks when trying to render using Java.

I've done extensive searching throughout the web, and many people have suggested the presence of  conflicting `js.jar` present in the application. This is not the case in the application I'm working on. The only javascript/rhino instances are those being imported through BIRT.

I've also attempted the following solutions:

- Excluding the bundled javascript and importing latest Rhino/javascript from Mozilla
- Updating BIRT to `4.4.1` and creating a report template with the latest BIRT designer
- Degrading the report template to only show one value returned by the DB (in this case 'name' of a dealership)

This project is using Maven, and is running in Tomcat 7 - using Java 6.

The database is using mysql.

More details can be provided if requested.

---

EDIT: Been fiddling around with this problem for a little bit and have found the following:

- Basic reports that do not hit the database render fine - even javascript expressions
- Once I attempt to get datasets out of a query, then the Invalid Javascript expression gets thrown, for e.g. in this section of the template: `<data id="624">
          <property name="dataSet">Dealership</property>
          <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
              <structure>
                  <property name="name">name</property>
                  <text-property name="displayName">name</text-property>
                  <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["name"]</expression>
                  <property name="dataType">string</property>
              </structure>
          </list-property>
          <property name="resultSetColumn">name</property>
      </data>`

  - Any value placed in the above `datasetRow` section throws an Invalid Javascript error

Comment: Does a very simple report work (i.e with just a title and a simple dynamic text such "Hello "+" world", without using the database)? Did you try to apply two separate "run" and "render" task (which is AFAIK the recommended approach) in the java app?

Comment: Just tried this:

Added the following line:

`<expression name="expression" type="javascript">"Hello" + "World" + params["testparam"]</expression>`

and it renders fine. 

I haven't split it into `run` and `render`, right now I'm only doing:


`task.run();`
`task.close();`


and it seems to be doing fine. I will try to do run and then render.


The fact that it works without a DB makes me think that the driver is acting up or something... not sure - I've looked into adding the driver (mysql) but can't find the proper maven dependency.

Comment: EDIT: MYSQL drivers seem to work because it actually hits my database with the right queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong with this issue.

We are using Maven and decided to check and see if there were conflicting libraries.

We found one: Apache.FOP.

Took it out and Birt worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be caused by version issues in birt pom.xml of the maven repository. I got many troubles with Maven in this version.

You should try this: set the BIRT maven dependency to "provided" in your project, and add "manually" all jars to your app from the [official Eclipse birt-runtime 4.4.0 package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/birt/downloads/drops/R-R1-4_4_0-201406111043/birt-runtime-4_4_0-20140611.zip). For example, on my side i created a custom local Maven dependency in Netbeans to handle this and it works pretty well. I hope it will help.

Comment: I've used it with maven before in a similar project using DB2 instead of MySQL and it works... so I'm not sure if it's the pom being the problem. Were you using mysql when you were running into these issues?

I'll still give your solution a go though, and I'll let you know the results.

Comment: No these Maven issues were not specific to MySql, so this might not be the same problem. If it worked in your case with DB2 it doesn't even worth to try what i suggested. How do you access MySQL from your report? JDBC datasource, Connection pool, JDBC for Query builder, ...? Is this datasource directly declared in the report, or linked from a .rptlibrary? What is the JVM version of your java app running environment?

Comment: The report uses the mysql JDBC driver - it's declared directly in the report.

Using Java 1.6.